# Apple Healthkit and Watch Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, apple-watch, healthkit

Is it possible to use and querying Healthkit through Iphone and Watch simulators?

Did a lot of search and only one mention in Xamarin Forum saying you can't, but nothing else.

Anybody could point out a link on that matter?

As of now the tests I've made on request authorization like this:

```
healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: writableTypes, read: readableTypes){ (success, error) in

        if(!success){
            print("Error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

Are resulting the above object error giving me "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement."

And, yes, the entitlement is proper informed.

Comment: For part of it, are you making sure the device accepted the HealthKit authorizations before you make a call to ask for the HealthKit data?  Usually if you're asking for authorization it pops up immediately when the app is run (in the simulator or on device).  I know if that has not been accepted before I try to use the Watch, I'll get the same error, etc.

Comment: Yes. If a try in a real Iphone the Healthkit opens asking for permissions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the device accepted the HealthKit authorizations before you make a call to ask for the HealthKit data. Usually if you're asking for authorization it pops up immediately when the app is run (in the simulator or on device). I know if that has not been accepted before I try to use the Watch, I'll get the same error, etc.

Comment: The code above is the first thing happening in my app. And when I run in a real Iphone or Iphone simulator Healthkit opens and asks for permission.

Comment: Perfect, then for the next step, do you accept all of the permissions and such?  So then that would also mean you provisioned the app for HealthKit etc, on the Capabilities tab.

Comment: Yes. I accepted all permissions and pressed allow in Healthkit app. Still no joy... I'm about to put my hands on a Watch device. After test it I'll post my results. Thanks for your precious time!